# Spring and Log4j ver 2 - XML configuration example

Tags: spring, log4j2

I am trying to configure **Log4j 2** in Spring XML configuration file for the first time (but unsuccessfully). I need to create two appenders - one for logging into console (>=DEBUG) and another for logging into database via JDBCAppender (>= INFO).

There is a problem because I don't know how to set another log level logger that differs from root logger.

Thank you for sharing some XML configuration sample. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the level on the appender ref.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
 <appenders>
   <appender name="A">
      ...
    </appender>
    <appender name="B">
      ...
    </appender>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="trace">
      <appender-ref ref="A" level="info"/>
      <appender-ref ref="B" level="debug"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```